# Speed up active user query

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query doesn't complete right now because the window is too large. Any way to speed it up?

```
select
    gs.date,
    (select count(distinct customer_id) 
     from messages 
     where direction = 'received' 
       and created_at between gs.date - interval '89 days' and gs.date)
from
    generate_series('2015-07-09'::date, current_date::date, interval '1 day') gs
order by gs.date;
```

Comment: Try a multicolumn index on `messages( direction, created_at )` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select
  gs.date,
  count(distinct(customer_id))
from
  messages
  inner join generate_series('2015-07-09'::date, current_date::date, interval '1 day') gs
where
  direction = 'received'
  and created_at between gs.date - interval '89 days' and gs.date
group by gs.date
order by gs.date
```

It will still be an expensive query (doing a rolling unique count like that is just an inherently expensive thing to calculate) but I think that will be faster than having a subquery in your select clause.  The query planner has more freedom to choose an efficient plan using a join and a `group by`.

Comment: Awesome, not sure why this is faster? (although it is...)

Comment: Running each of them with `explain select ...` will show the query plan; it should be possible to discern the reason from those